# Websphere Scripting - Error while SyncNode

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, wsadmin, jacl

Below is the jacl script which I use for syncing the Node in WAS 7.

```
    #Sync Node Changes
    puts "Begin SyncNode.." 
    set Sync1 [$AdminControl completeObjectName type=NodeSync,process=nodeagent,node=Profile01Node600,*]
    set Sync2 [$AdminControl completeObjectName type=NodeSync,process=nodeagent,node=Profile02Node601,*]
    $AdminControl invoke $Sync1 sync
    $AdminControl invoke $Sync2 sync
    puts "SyncNode Complete"
```

The environment is clustered, post deployment of the EAR file, I'm invoking this jacl script to sync the changes to Nodes.
The error I get when running the script:

```
    WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node wAMLDmgrNode using SOAP connector; The type of process is: DeploymentManager
    Begin SyncNode..
    WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "xxx/xxx/xxx.jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7025E: Error found in String ""; cannot create ObjectName.
```

What is the reason for Sync1 being ''?
Do we need to use *process=nodeagent* in the command?
What will be the result if the nodeagent is started and stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

```
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "xxx/xxx/xxx.jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7025E: Error found in String ""; cannot create ObjectName.
```

... tells that the ObjectName was not found. Most likely:

- your nodeagent is down
- there is a typo in node name (Profile01Node600 & Profile01Node601)

You can check which nodeagents (their NodeSync MBeans) are available by running this command:

```
$AdminControl queryNames WebSphere:*,type=NodeSync
```

Based on the output you can fix the typo.

If unavailability of nodeagent is the issue, then you can cater for that in your script by checking if `completeObjectName` returned an empty string.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks @Marcin :) Yeah the nodeagent was down and Sync2 returned empty String. I need to alter the script to check for empty String.